# How do I copy a cell depending on the value of the previous row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm stuck with the following problem:

I've got a spreadsheet where I want to replace a value of a cell B1 with the value of a cell B2 underneath if a corresponding cell A1 (value lower than 30) if followed by a cell A2 with a value lower than 80.

I guess it should have a form of:

if A<30 and A+1<80
  then copy B+1 to B

**Here's an example of the original list:**

```
A       B  
9   31.395020  
60  33.167969  
81  40.399902  
5   41.425293  
60  44.031738  
81  49.647949  
6   50.671875  
81  58.111816
```

**That's what I want to get:**

```
A       B  
9   33.167969   
60  33.167969  
81  40.399902  
5   44.031738  
60  44.031738  
81  49.647949  
6   50.671875  
81  58.111816
```

Can I use an if-statement or do I need a macro for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simple formula you asked for:

```
=IF(AND(A3<80,A2<30),B3,B2)
```

[image: ExcelSimpleFormula]

Although I would be curious what practical purpose you would need this for. Good Luck.

Comment: great. that was much easier than I expected, I should blush. I need it for analysing EEG data and have to use response time instead of the stimulus onset as the software that I'll use can't make it